# google photo set uploaded album to public

Tags: photo

How to set the google photo album to public when creating using java api

I am using AlbumEntry to create album using PicasawebService class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the

```
AlbumEntry.setAccess(String access)
```

method

By default the ablum created will be private. To explicity make the album public you can use **public** as the method parameter.

So you need to call

```
 albumEntryObject.setAccess("public");
```

before calling the

```
picasawebService.insert(..)
```

method.

Comment: Is there any provided constant for the value **public** from google api?

Comment: I looked into the doc, but didn't find any constant, have a look at **https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/photos/AlbumEntry#setAccess(java.lang.String)**